# windows phone 8.1 application support in windows phone 10 or not

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am new here. I made `windows phone 8.1 cordova` application and it working smoothly.

I just need to know my `windows phone 8.1` will work in `windows phone 10` or not?

Please info in details is appropriated.

Thank You

Comment: Apps built for Windows 8.1 run fine on Windows 10 devices, but to take advantage of the many new features in the Windows 10 platform or to extend your app to run on additional device families, you'll need to migrate them. - https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Preview/03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows 10 Mobile devices will run Windows Phone 8.1 apps.

See the [OS versions and package distribution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188601.aspx) documentation in the [Guidance for app package management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188601.aspx) on MSDN for several tables which explain how multiple uploaded packages will deploy to specific OS targets. If you publish a Windows Phone 8.1 app but not a Universal Windows Platform app then the Windows Phone 8.1 app will deploy to Windows 10 Mobile devices.

You can test this yourself in the [Windows 10 Mobile emulators](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=698769) even if you don't have a Windows 10 Mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I will work perfectly fine. all windows phone 8.1(Win-RT) apps will work in windows phone 10.

Comment: That's great.. But is there any particular documentation which mentioned that all windows phone 8.1 app work in windows phone 10. I need to give proof check to my superior. Thank you.

Comment: I have listen that in some dev video on channel 9  but right now cann't remember the exect video link. I have also one app in in windows phone 8.1(universal) and it is working perfectly fine on one of my windows phone 10 device.

Comment: ok Thank you. will wait for some other answer who can give more details answer. Thank you. As i have not much reputation so i can't upvote your answer. When i have i'll do for sure. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yus all windows phone 8/8.1 application supports windows 10 mobile.

Comment: Thanks @Vinay but can you provide documentation link which can give details about it.

Comment: I have already many windows phone 8.1 application and 1 windows phone 8 application and those all run properly on windows phone 10. but lil bit confuse about upload app on store .

Comment: actully.. you can already see link of store for windows 10 device in builds information it self. you just upload windows phone 8.1 build. i just check my console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to tell but to test it out on Windows 10 mobile. The reason i am saying is this because certain APIs behave differently on Windows 10. For example: A few TileNofication Templates defined in Windows phone 8.1 will not work well with Windows 10. This is from a first hand experience as i had to test a very big cloud application developed in Windows phone 8.1 on Windows 10 mobile.

I am not sure how much has been fixed in the latest builds but there were quite a few issues in Windows 10 mobile that were being addressed. For example, not being able to attach to Background Transfer uploads.

Querying the known folders is quite different in Windows 10 mobile. But again, as i said, i have not tested any of these in the latest builds that has come in the last 1-2 weeks. You will have to test your completely from end to end.

Comment: thanks golldy.. that helpful info will test when i deploy in windows 10 emulator.